# What format is this and how to get value "lal" and "pila" from it

Tags: post-meta, array

[2] => a:2:{i:0;s:3:"lal";i:1;s:4:"pila";}
saved by wordpress function as an array

```
add_post_meta($contestid, 'suraj', array('lal','pila'));
```

and retrieved by the function

```
get_post_meta($contestid);
```

Comment: That `a:2:{i:0;s:3:"lal";i:1;s:4:"pila";}` is a *serialized* string representing the original array in a format that can be saved in the database, and see the [`get_post_meta()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) for details on how to correctly retrieve a single meta value.

Comment: hi thank for reply. got more info from https://wpengine.com/support/wordpress-serialized-data/